# Admin authentication test failed for LDAP Server(ApachedDS) Integration

Tags: ldap, integration, openfire

[image]
here is the LDIF file for ApacheDS LDAP Server Connection:

```
  dn: dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: domain
objectClass: top
dc: example


dn: ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: Users


dn: ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: Groups


dn: cn=Adan Abrams,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: Adan Abrams
sn: Abrams
description: 19741108000000Z
employeeNumber: 7
givenName: Adan
telephoneNumber: 254-323-1920
telephoneNumber: 902-451-7619
uid: aabrams
userPassword:: c2VjcmV0

dn: cn=admin,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: admin
sn: admin
description: 19741108000000Z
employeeNumber: 7
givenName: admin
telephoneNumber: 254-323-1920
telephoneNumber: 902-451-7619
uid: admin
userPassword:: admin
```

User Mapping Test connection is successful. Only problem I face is the page for Administrator Authentication where I can user "admin" as Admin but can not authenticate with the password same in LDIF file and that's why when I go ahead and completed the whole config for OpenFire and try  to login Admin Console, it can not login with that  admin user also.

Let me know if I need to do any other configs like openfire.xml or miss something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: facing the same issue

Comment: If you want to go through in detail with issue with screenshot: https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/56589

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved.... **Actually password was stored as HEX with some algorithms in LDAP Server by default.** I changed it to plain text,,, and now can login to admin console with admin user. Thanks.